# Creating sum of all numbers within a sequence

Tags: java

Write an algorithm that, given sequence *seq* of *n* numbers where 3 <= *n* <= 1000 and each number *k* in *seq* 1 <= *k* <= 200, finds maximum sum by repeatedly removing one number from *seq*, except for first and last number in *seq*, and adding its value to sum of two adjacent numbers. Algorithm ends when there are only two numbers left.

For example:
Max sum for sequence [2, 1, 5, 3, 4] is 31.

So far I've written brute force algorithm checking all possible combinations but it's not well suited for large sequences.

```java
public static int solve(ArrayList<Integer> seq, int sumOfRemoved) {
  if (seq.size() == 3) {
    return seq.get(0) + seq.get(1) + seq.get(2) + sumOfRemoved;
  }
  LinkedList<Integer> maxValues = new LinkedList<>();
  for (int i = 1; i < seq.size() - 1; i++) {
    ArrayList<Integer> clone = (ArrayList<Integer>) seq.clone();
    clone.remove(i);
    int sum = seq.get(i - 1) + seq.get(i) + seq.get(i + 1);
    maxValues.add(solve(clone, sum));
  }
  int max = 0;
  for (int val : maxValues) {
    max = Math.max(max, val + sumOfRemoved);
  }
  return max;
}
```

My question is, is there more efficient algorithm solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

From the top of my head I would use a greedy approach, always remove the lowest available number so the potential sum of later steps lessens the least this way. But I do not have a proof for this finding the top possible sum, especially not at 0:21 on Monday :-).

With 2,***1***,5,3,4(0) it would go to 2,5,***3***,4(2+1+5=8), then to 2,***5***,4(8+5+3+4=20), and end at 2,4(20+2+5+4=31). So it finds your sum, but this is just one case.